# Dismiss ListView when user taps outside of it

Tags: listview, react-native

I have a ListView component and I need it do dismiss when a user taps outside of it. I've tried using the onBlur prop but apparently ListView doesn't have that built-in. What other options do I have?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of listening to an equivalent of `onBlur` for ListView (which I don't think exists), use a Touchable* component outside of it to catch the `onPress` and fire a method to dismiss the ListView. You could wrap it like so.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.dismissListView.bind(this)} style={styles.wrapper}>
  <ListView style={style.listView} .../>
</TouchableOpacity>

style.wrapper = {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
  bottom: 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That would work, but I need the outside of the listview to be pressable as it contains other components.

Comment: Does tapping outside focus some other component, or just dismiss? You could also pass a callback into those other components that would trigger the `dismissListView` method.